# John plays games on his smartphone

Tags: pattern, video-games

John likes playing Clash Royale but does not like Clash Of Clans.
John likes Pokemon Go but does not like Minecraft.
John likes playing Temple Run but does not like playing Vainglory.
John also likes Talking Tom and Flappy Bird but does not like Geometry Dash and PUBG.

Can someone introduce a new game to John and explain why?

Comment: Athin's answer is a perfectly good answer. You should add new examples for that answer to be incorrect.

Comment: Geometry Dash has 2 words, which invalidates the current answer. Is that intended?

Comment: Agh I thought I was onto it with IOS versions

Comment: Is there any reason TT and FB are grouped together?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe I'll introduce him to

> 2048 puzzle

and not

> Sniper 3D

because

> the first one of all the pairs is played in portrait mode, while the second ones have to be played in landscape mode.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I'll introduce him

> Mobile Legends

and not

> League Of Legends

simply because

> the title has 2 words.

Comment: Nice observation but that wasn't the answer I was looking for! (I did not see that myself) :P